# Reset accidentally voted post

Tags: discussion

Wish I'm not the first to experience this.

How to reset a vote if you mistakenly click up or down vote button. I wanted to upvote an answer but have clicked the upvote of another answer (which really not a good answer) which has 0 votes. Anyway to reset it? If I click on downvote it gives him -1 which I don't want to do :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to undo an upvote, you can click the upvote button again; If you want to undo a downvote, you can click the downvote again.

:D

This can only be done within a 5 minute window after your vote unless the post is edited.

References:

- [Vote too old to be changes unless post is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited)
- [Radically reduced the window for undoing votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046)
- [5 minute window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38759/192215)
- [Limits on how I can cast change and retract votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)

Comment: (doh) I'd say thank you, if u don't mind :D

Comment: is there a time limit within which you have to revert your vote ? or can u revert it anytime u want ?

Comment: Yes there is a limit! I'll update my answer.